In Hebrews 2:7, why is "And set him over the works of your hands" put in brackets or even completely removed from all current translations?
(Hebrews 2:5-9 ESV translation)

For it was not to angels that God subjected the world to come, of
which we are speaking. It has been testified somewhere,
“What is man, that you are mindful of him, or the Son of Man, that you
care for Him? You made Him for a little while lower than the angels;
you have crowned Him with glory and honor [AND SET HIM OVER THE WORKS OF YOUR HANDS], putting everything in subjection under His feet.”
Now in putting everything in subjection to Him, He left nothing
outside His control. At present, we do not yet see everything in
subjection to Him. But we see Him who for a little while was made
lower than the angels, namely Jesus, crowned with glory and honor
because of the suffering of death, so that by the grace of God He
might taste death for everyone.

So why is that extended portion of Hebrews 2:7, which is actually present in the Greek texts and quoted from Psalm 8:6, removed in most current translations?
Traditional commentators have made disturbing notes such as, "We think it shouldn't be there" or, "the author should not have put it there", or, "it does not help the author to have it here", etc.
It is therefore blatantly obvious that translator committees are forcing their personal theological biases onto the word of God by removing the key portion of this passage to obfuscate the truth and accommodate their infamous doctrines of Trinitarianism and dyophisite "God-man" deification christology.
To the contrary, it is clear from these passages that God created all things Himself, and not through the hands of Jesus as a "co-creator" or an "agent of creation". Nevertheless, God did create all things for Jesus (because of Jesus), and with him in mind and propose; setting Jesus over the work of His (the Father God's) hands.
(This controversy is directly correlated to the "dia" passages controversy)
Should "διά" (dia) be translated as "through" or "because of" in the five NT verses pertaining to God creating the world for Jesus?
Your thoughts?

This question can be improved by removing or rewording the highly emotive wording such as "blows my mind", "blatantly forcing their personal theological bias", and "it's clear to me that..."

@MikeSangrey - I adjusted it for you, but my main concerns are still fully fielded.

Bruce Metzger doesn't put this variation in his textual commentary.  This is what is in the critical apparatus.  ¦ marks a different variation, and txt marks the variation they decide on.
7 ⸆ (Ps 8,7) και κατεστησας αυτον επι τα εργα των χειρων σου א A C D* P 
Ψ 0243. 0278. 6. 33. 81. 104. 365. 629. 1505. 1739. 1881. 2464 lat 
(syp.h**) co
     ¦ txt 46 B D2 K L 630. 1175. 1241  vgms

Nestle, E., & Nestle, E. (2012). Nestle-Aland: NTG Apparatus Criticus (B. Aland, K. Aland, J. Karavidopoulos, C. M. Martini, & B. M. Metzger, Eds.; 28. revidierte Auflage, p. 659). Deutsche Bibelgesellschaft.
Both variations have significant witnesses. The omission has the oldest witness, a papyrus, p46.
To make their decision they would ask the question, "Is it more likely that a copyist would leave out the text or add the text."  Because the text is in the passage quoted, they chose it was most likely added.
To do a more thorough job, they would divide the witnesses into the Alexandrian, Western, and Byzantine text to compare the peculiarity of each family of texts.  Probably not necessary for this case.

What happens in the actual feet-on-the-ground translation practice is the translators will chose (ie. settle on) a published Greek Text.  Today this is most often the Nestle Aland text (Novum Testamentum Graece, 28th edition) or, for those of the Textus Receptus tradition, the Textus Receptus.  Slightly older, but still relatively modern translations used Westcott and Hort. The SBL text was published in 2010 and the publishing license is designed to be much more open.  For translation, other critical texts are sometimes consulted.  When a critical text is published, all textual variants are reviewed. If you don't know, the textual variant which is chosen by the committee, is typically done by vote, and sometimes the results are rated.  BTW, work is underway on a machine generated Greek text with the intent of providing one that is programmatically determined. They hope to remove most creeping-in bias and provide the means to analyze the programmatic workflow (ie. algorithmic decisions). Work, so far, shows very significant agreement with the SBL Text. (See Center for New Testament Restoration)
The Nestle Aland text does not include the clause listed in the OP.  It cites it in the Textual Apparatus, and so lists the relevant manuscripts.  Westcott and Hort put the clause in brackets.  SBL follows the Nestle-Aland text and the Westcott and Hort text suggests by way of brackets that the clause was simply not in the original.  Translators will review the Textual Critics decisions, but, more often than not, will be reluctant to go against those trained in the tricky Art and Science of Textual Criticism.  Some commentators suggest that some scribes added the clause from Psalms in the copy's margin. This scribal addition is a known practice, though rare, and there's no hard evidence it was done here.
The attack on translators by the OP is unwarranted.  That's especially true when the theological attack is obviously countered by other clear texts.  Texts discussed in the link the OP provided (which he calls a controversy).  It's a bit ironic to me that the OP's argument, as strongly worded as it is, is more likely to be with the author of Hebrews.  Since, the author appears to have purposefully left out the clause that's part of the quote from Psalms.  We need to accept original authorial choice.
I don't know whether or not there's a StackExchange site for textual criticism.  But, I suggest taking up the discussion there if the site exists.  For, this is more a Textual Criticism question than it is a Hermeneutics one.
However, if one assumes the Textual Critic experts are wrong, then there's the question of how the text relates to the surrounding text.  Also possible is how the clause relates to other relevant texts (like the ones that clearly state that Jesus was the agent through which the creation was made). Alas, one quickly gets into a theological battle.  See the link provided by the OP.
Lastly, NT quotes from OT texts tend to be topological (ie Topic-related).  In other words, the assumption is that the OT author did not intend an identical, all-possible-contexts meaning.  The OT author expressed a concept within the OT context (ie topic); the NT author takes the topologically relevant idea (the topic) and applies it to the NT context.  Given that, it's not much of a stretch to think that a NT author would leave out a piece of the text that isn't relevant to his topic.  Relatedly, we have examples of NT texts that obviously, purposefully modify the OT quotation.  NT authors are also inspired.
The OP's suggestion that the "extended portion of Hebrews 2:7, which is actually present in the Greek texts" is misstated at best and possibly deceptive.  It would be better stated with, "...in some Greek texts..." which is demonstrably true.  Consult any quality Textual Apparatus of Hebrews 2 for proof.

+1 Excellent information regarding the challenges of translation! One should always be careful not to ascribe motives although it can be hard to avoid bias.

Dieter - You said, "One should always be careful not to ascribe motives although it can be hard to avoid bias." Yeah, this is exactly what the orthodox establishment Trinitarians have done for 1,600 years, and 400 years since the KJV. They hijacked hundred of passages and altered them to fit their agenda, even inserting an entire new verse in 1 John 5:7 which is the most Trinitarian verse it there, alongside the infamous Matthew 28:19 and Isaiah 9:6.

Translations are rarely actually based on the SBL text, as it's not a full critical text, it's not based on all the original manuscripts, but instead a compilation of other critical texts. The gold standard is still the Nestle-Aland or UBS text (two publishers of the same text, with different apparatus.) Also, this is the site for textual criticism.

@curiousdannii.  Thanks!  I stand corrected.  I've edited the answer to reflect your observation.  The correction does not alter my answer in a substantive way in so far as the statements I made referring to SBL apply to the Nestle Aland text.  That is, both leave the Greek clause out of the original since it has been deemed a later, scribal addition.  Also, I've cleaned up a ambiguous sentence or two to make them clearer.

Mike Sangrey - how in God's name is that a scribal addition?! The author of Hebrews is literally quoting Psalm 8:6, and the redacted portion is present in some of the earliest NT Greek texts. What are the grounds for trusting the texts with the key portion redacted?!

How a scribal addition?  Well, the original author left it out.  The scribe, just like you, felt it was missed.  Regarding "the grounds", the Psalmist topic has to do with human beings--that is:  human beings ruling over creation.  The author of Hebrews takes that topic and applies it to Jesus.  If he had included the portion you refer to as "redacted", he would be saying something about Jesus that the author of Hebrews wanted to avoid.  That is, that Jesus, just like all other humans beings, was not the agent of creation.  This would have contradicted other scripture.

Because the text in Hebrews 2:6b-8a is a direct quote from Psalm 8 as you noted, one would think that the missing phrase should be present in Hebrews. The footnote in the ESV explains this as follows:

Some manuscripts insert and set him over the works of your hands.

You can compare the different English versions here:
https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/Hebrews%202:7
It seems that some manuscripts do include this phrase, but remember that NOT all manuscripts used by translators have an equal reputation for reliability.
As you can see, translators disagree on this point. It could be argued that the author of Hebrews quoted only the parts he considered contextually relevant.
The phrase missing from Hebrews is present in both the Septuagint and the Dead Sea Scrolls, so it's less likely that the author of Hebrews was quoting from a variant manuscript.
Personally, I'd remain true to Psalm 8, but I can see the desire of those translators who did not include the phrase, to remain true to the manuscripts they relied on, which I respect.

Dieter - You respect that they removed it? I honestly despise that! By removing the phrase "set Him over the work of Your hands", translators are eagerly trying to reinforce the false belief that Jesus created the world for himself, and not that God created the world for Jesus. This is an abomination.

Dieter - Hebrews 1:10 is not God saying to Jesus that he (Jesus) created all things, but that God created all things for Jesus and with Jesus in mind. Jesus was the propose for God's creation.

@Joshua B, The goal of a translator of integrity is to translate the given text, not make corrections to the text or interpolations based solely on doctrinal positions. In the in Codex Vaticanus, the copyists likewise didn't make judgements on variant source texts, but instead included distme-obelos symbols that allowed the reader to decide on any such issues. I respect their integrity. As I said, I'd include the text from Psalm 8, but I'd certainly add a note.

Hebrews 2:7-10 quotes Psalm 8:5-7
Hebrews 2:7 without the omission. Literal Standard Version

You made him [a] little less than messengers, You crowned him with glory and honor, And set him over the works of Your hands,

Hebrews 2:7 with the omission. New Revised Standard Version

You have made them for a little while lower than the angels; you have crowned them with glory and honor,

Psalm 8:5-7 Literal Standard Version

You make him a little lower than the gods [[or God]] And surround him with glory and majesty You cause him to rule Over the works of Your hands, You have placed all under his feet. Sheep and oxen, all of them, And also beasts of the field,

This shows that Psalm 8:5-7 refers to humanity, not a single person, as different versions like the New Revised Standard Version show in its use of the word "them" instead of "him".
In comparison, the author of the book of Hebrews applies Psalm 8:5-6 exclusively to Jesus.  Psalm 8 talks about God giving man/humanity dominion. Thus, the issue of omission and the subjection of all things should be considered in light of all of what the rest of the Bible says about the subject.
Psalm 8:5-7 shows that it was God who gave man dominion over the "works of His hand". Examining whose hands work the creation,  Hebrews 1;10, Psalm 102:25. Psalm 8:5-7 and Hebrews 2:7 show that even if other translations choose to omit the phrase [and set Him over the works of Your hands], putting everything in subjection under His feet] the truth about the God of Jesus as the only Creator does not change.
Psalm 102:25 LSV

You founded the earth before time, And the heavens [are] the work of Your hands.

Whose hands? YHWH's hands.
Psalm 102:25 is a prayer to YHWH/God, YHWH/God is not the speaker in Psalm 102:25
Hebrews 1:10 LSV

and, “You, LORD, founded the earth at the beginning, And the heavens are a work of Your hands.

Whose hands? The God of Jesus or Jesus'?
Hebrews 2:7 LSV

You made him [a] little less than messengers, You crowned him with glory and honor, And set him over the works of Your hands,

The heavens are the work of God's hands, not Jesus' hands. It would be absurd to say that Jesus placed the work of his hands to himself. Jesus is given authority over the works of God; the works of his Father's hands.

Fantastic response. It makes sense and I totally agree. Now we can return to the dia controversy: Do the "di" passages say that all things were made "through" Jesus or "because of" Jesus? I suspect the latter, that God made all things because of Jesus; for his purpose.

@JoshuaB. Is there link that you can provide for me to study why you suspect "God made all things because of Jesus? "Through" IMO has the concept of an agent or intermediary,. I remembered we had a discussion via comment about this under my answer to one of your question and we agreed to certain topics and disagreed on other topics.

Alex Balilo - Yes I have a study on this topic, see it here: https://onegodworship.com/is-jesus-the-creator-an-examination-of-colossians-115-18/

@JoshuaB. Very good read. Thanks. That was why my answer to your question about "dia"  show that the sudden appearance of verses contrasting John the Baptist to Jesus does not make sense if John 1 was talking about Genesis creation. The link you provided, IMO, support it.

Alex Balilo - John 1 is actually about the Genesis creation. Jesus was in the beginning with God, and Jesus was himself a god (a divine spiritual son). All things were made by God (the Father) because of him, that is, for Jesus. God made all things with the word of His mouth, and Jesus is the external manifestation of God's word, therefore Jesus is called "the Word". Jesus was created on Day 1 of the Genesis Week as the Light of the world, the Son of Light, as the first of God's works of old (Prov. 8:22). The Word made flesh, Jesus, is the Angel of YHWH, the Chief Angel Michael. (Gal. 4:14)

@JoshuaB. I have to disagree with your view that John 1 is actually about the Genesis creation. Consider, why would John 1 :8 say that John the Baptist was not the light when it is obvious that light already existed before John the Baptist was born? I can give my detailed answer about this if you ask a question about it instead of commenting partly about it.

Alex Balilo - John 1:8 is simply saying that John the Baptist was not the Light (the Messiah), but that he was the one in the wilderness who prepared the way for the incarnation of the Light.

Answer
In most of the versions I have, the clause “And set him over the works of Your hands” in Hebrews 2:7 is very much given as normal text.
I don’t find any difference it makes (in the implied case) because it talks about the saints of God, in both Psalms and Hebrews.
[Man is mentioned in singular as a representative of humanity in Hebrews chapter 2. This is true because the inspired author contrasts “man” against “angels” in plural]
Explanation
Hebrews 2:5-8 is CONTRASTED with Hebrews 2:9-10.
Hebrews 2:5-8:-
These verses are talking about the saintly believers who will be in the blessed first resurrection. These are the patriarchs, prophets, apostles and saints.
These are the people who are “crowned with glory and honor”.
How?

“But whom He predestinated, these He also called; and whom He called,
these He also justified; and whom He justified, these He also
glorified” (Rom 8:30).


“And if children, also heirs; truly heirs of God, and joint-heirs of
Christ, if indeed we suffer together, that we may also be
glorified together” (Rom 8:17).

These saints will be “set over the works of Your hands” (verse 7).
Really?

“Do you not know that the saints will judge the world?” (1 Cor
6:2).


“Do you not know that we shall judge angels?” (1 Cor 6:3).


“But the saints of the Most High shall receive the kingdom and
possess the kingdom forever, even forever and ever” (Dan 7:18).

But now we do not yet see all things being subject to him (the saints).
Why?

“These all (the saints of God) died by way of faith, not having
received the promises, but seeing them from afar, and being
persuaded” (Heb 11:13).
“And having obtained witness through the faith, these all (saints)
did not obtain the promise” (Heb 11:39).

CONTRAST
Hebrews 2:9-10:-
These verses talk about Lord Jesus who received back the glory and honor He had with the Father before the worlds were created.

“And now Father, glorify Me with Yourself, with the glory which I
had with You before the existence of the world” (John 17:5).

[Here, Jesus is talking about the same glory He shared with His Father. This is not any lesser glory but the same glory God the Father held!]

“which none of the rulers of this age has known. For if they had
known, they would not have crucified the Lord of glory” (1 Cor
2:8).

[Throughout the Old Testament, Jehovah and His glory are mentioned several times. Paul is clearly referring to that by calling Jesus, the Lord of glory]
This Jesus was made a little lower than angels so that He could die on behalf of all humanity to redeem them.

“Christ Jesus, who subsisting in the form of God, thought it not
robbery to be equal with God, but emptied Himself, taking the form
of a slave, having become in the likeness of men and being found in
fashion as a man, He humbled Himself, having become obedient until
death, even the death of a cross” (Phlp 2:5-8).

Evidence Hebrews 2:5-8 is not about Jesus
In Heb 2:8, it says:

“But now we do not yet see all things being subject to him”.

This is not about Jesus because Jesus declared:

“And coming up Jesus talked with them, saying, All authority in
Heaven and on earth was given to Me” (Mat 28:18).


“All things were yielded up to Me by My Father” (Mat 11:27).
"The Father loves the Son and has given all things into His hand
(John 3:35).

So, all things in Heaven and Earth are already subjected to Him!
Works of Whose Hands?
If we go strictly by the Scripture, then it is works of Jesus’ hands!
How can we be sure?!
Yes, we can be very sure because in Hebrews 1:10, God the Father addresses Jesus and says:

“You, Lord (Yahweh), at the beginning founded the earth, and the
heavens are works of Your (Jesus’) hands”.

Conclusion
The presence of Hebrews 2:7 does not change anything except proving the already established truth that the saints of the first resurrection will rule the world, ages and the angels, that is, the works of Yahweh’s (Jesus’) hands.
